# Registrar won't permit subdomain DNS delegation

Tags: dns-hosting

A client's host and domain registrar, Aruba, tell me I can't delegate a subdomain's DNS management to external namesevers.

The intention was to point the subdomain to a Heroku app and leave the client's main domain name and website as is (hosted on Aruba's nameservers).

Is this normal that a registrar would disallow this? Am i just getting brushed off? I'd like to hear opinion before going back to them, thanks

Comment: that include adding a CNAME?

Comment: They allow adding a CNAME record, but that doesn't work for this as I need to delegate to third party nameservers (Heroku's). So I need to add a NameServer record for the subdomain, as I understand it.

Comment: That's strange, unusual and bizarre.

Comment: Is it yeah? It's certainly very annoying, I just wanted to know if I can oblige them to do it really.